# How do I persist a ServiceStack session cookie?

Tags: .net, cookies, servicestack

In our company we are considering to use ServiceStack for exposing domain specific services through REST/SOAP APIs and consume those services from multiple backends including websites. A very common SOA scenario. Our services require authentication as well as session support.

Do I have to persist both ss-id and ss-pid cookies in order to make authentication and sessions work consistently across multiple requests from the same client?

My preference would be to just pick and save one ... so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RememberMe](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L18) property when the user authenticates to your service will determine whether the Users Session is saved under the Temporary SessionId (ss-id) or Permanent SessionId (ss-pid), this preference is specified in the Users `ss-opt=temp/perm` Cookie.

By default if `RememberMe=true` isn't specified, ServiceStack defaults to storing the users session against the temporary `ss-id` cookie, in which case is the only one that needs to be sent.